# Push button latch circuit - switch issue

Tags: transistors, switching, latch, latching

I have built a single push on/off latching circuit as per the diagram. It runs from 12 V.

It works, but the issues I have is that first, it is already on when I connect power, it should start off, second, I have to flick the switch extremely fast for it to turn off, like the switch has to close for only a fraction of a second, any longer and the LED I have attached just flickers but stays on.

How can I make sure it is off when power is connected? And how can I make the button press longer, like 0.5 s to 1 s?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv1wzU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think you'll need to **not use** that circuit, @GrantLee . If it isn't working for you, then either you didn't build it correctly or else it wasn't designed well. (I'm assuming that your LED is connected to the collector of Q8 here.) And just a quick glance tells me it's not designed well. Did you get this from some web site? Or design it yourself? (If yourself, that's fine. I'm not dumping on you. But it has problems.)

Comment: This circuit was found on various electronic web sites, including this one, and on YouTube. The LED is connected to the collector of Q8 via a 2n3906 transistor. What are the problems that you see with it?

Comment: I don't see what I'd want to see in terms of positive feedback and state, @GrantLee . So I would expect to get just what you described getting. Something that depends upon your finger's interaction with the switch; the duration between these events and the duration of the event, too. I'm not offering to perform a time domain analysis for you. It's not worth the effort to me. I'd just design something different, is all.

Comment: With respect to the circuit starting up engaged, @GrantLee , this is imho due to parasitics (and perhaps your solderless breadboard, if using one.) Try supplying the 9 V power to the circuit by using a series 2.2 Ohm resistor and a parallel 1000 uF capacitor, picking off the power to the circuit from the newly added cap. This should slow things down enough to allow the circuit to start consistently **off**. The fast application of power and parasitics is, I believe, what's starting it **on**. I agree with Jason that, ideally, it should start **off**. But it doesn't. That's likely why.

Comment: @GrantLee I just took a moment on the circuit to get some of the basics when the switch is held down. The problem with the timing of your finger is that R22 and R23 are supplying about 9uA (not quite) into C16. Given enough time held down, the switch voltage gradually rises up sufficiently to engage Q8 and turn it on. The period of time should be about 500 mV/(9 uA/1 uF) or about 50 ms or so. Shorter than this and you are fine. Longer? Not so much. You can change the time. But it always must be held LESS, not MORE. Just the way it works. Long-hold is always bad.

Comment: @GrantLee A good design would be oppositely arranged so that momentary pulses of less than some number -- say 20 ms? -- would not toggle. (Debouncing is nice to have.) But anything longer would cause toggling, regardless of how long the momentary is held. This is probably easier to arrange so that the toggle takes place "upon release."

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple starting point:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOn87k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

After some long time with the momentary switch open and assuming that whatever is at \$N_1\$ is weakly holding \$Q_1\$ **off**, then \$C_1\$ will charge up to \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$. Closing the momentary switch now will immediately dump charge into \$Q_1\$'s base, causing it to turn **on** and pull down hard on \$R_2\$. Both the active base and the passive \$R_2\$ will now discharge \$C_1\$ -- very rapidly at first and then more slowly, later. If held continuously, \$Q_1\$ will eventually find a quiescent point, with \$Q_1\$ just enough in active mode to overcome the weak hold via \$N_1\$. In short, it will be an analog circuit while the switch is held closed and not really digital. When released again, the momentary no longer connects that loop and \$N_1\$ could re-establish the weakly held **off** state of \$Q_1\$ and then  \$C_1\$ will charge back up to \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$.

It's a start.

Add another BJT to "weakly" hold \$Q_1\$ **off** to complete this early picture:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fulT9w.png)</sup>

Will need a way to also weakly hold \$Q_1\$ **on**, too. This is, after all, going to be a two-state device:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Vxx4.png)</sup>

Now, perhaps something similar to what's working with \$Q_1\$ already at the base of \$Q_2\$ and tied in such a way that \$Q_1\$'s state controls \$Q_2\$'s state:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK60kB.png)</sup>

Does this have two states?

Assume \$Q_1\$ **off**. Then \$R_1\$ pulls up on both \$R_2\$ and \$R_5\$. Both \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ will charge up, but \$C_2\$ will be limited by \$Q_2\$'s base. \$Q_2\$ will definitely be **on** and \$C_1\$ will charge up to whatever the \$R_1\$+\$R+5\$ divider voltage allows it.

Assume \$Q_1\$ **on**. Then both \$R_2\$ and \$R_5\$ will pull down on \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$, both of which will discharge. \$Q_2\$ will turn **off** in time. But with \$R_3\$ via \$R_4\$ pulling up on the base of \$Q_1\$ it will stay **on**.

Given the right component values, the above is workable.

It won't handle an external load (much.) Adding that capability:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKosNc.png)</sup>

Now it's just a matter of supplying values.

\$C_2\$'s voltage is \$V_{_\text{C}}\approx 700\:\text{mV}\$ when \$Q_1\$ is **off** and \$Q_2\$ is **on**. In the opposite case, both \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ voltages are \$V_{_\text{A}}=V_{_\text{C}}\approx 100\:\text{mV}\$. What's key here is that the other state of \$C_1\$ should be about halfway to \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$ to make two very distinct states. Ratiometric is good as it helps with tolerating a wider range of supply voltages.

Solving, find that \$R_5\to R_1\$ as \$V_{_\text{CC}}\to\infty\$ and that \$R_5\approx 0.72\cdot R_1\$ when \$V_{_\text{CC}}=5\:\text{V}\$. That's a helpful boundary range to know. There may be other considerations for \$R_5\$, but that's a starting thought.

Another thing to be dealt with carefully is \$V_{_\text{B}}\$ must be arranged so that it turns the PFET **off** when \$Q_2\$ is **off** and that the PFET is **on** when \$Q_2\$ is **on**. \$R_3\$ will have to be carefully considered as both \$R_4\$ and \$R_6\$ are otherwise similarly involved in both cases.

I'm not interested in the web schematic. It's not well-designed. I'm open to helping with values for the above. But only if there's interest. Otherwise, this is my answer and that's that.

Answer (score 3):

> This circuit was found on various electronic web sites

Sometimes that's a problem: the circuit might not have been tested, or might have been a starting point for further exploration. It's not a given it's supposed to work at all.

> The LED is connected to the collector of Q8 via a 2n3906 transistor.

Please edit the schematic to add that transistor, by clicking "Edit" on the question, then "Edit this schematic" under the schematic in the preview below the edit window:

[image]

This answer will be updated once you present the complete circuit as-built.

The part of the circuit that you had shown is equivalent to a two-inverter "state keeper" - a memory cell, with an additional inverter that charges a capacitor. The button connects the inverted state to the memory cell's input, flipping its state. The capacitor is driven through large resistances R22-R23, intended so that the button can be pressed for some time and the capacitor will be essentially static while that happens. The time constant of the capacitor voltage is approximately 1μ*1MΩ=1s. So, if the button is depressed for a fraction of a second, the capacitor voltage is "constant".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDDQJc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, we can derive an equivalent circuit that highlights the functional blocks and hides their implementation somewhat.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftSV6S.png)</sup>

Alas, the overall approach is problematic. We don't want the circuit to be sensitive to the duration of the button press. The memory cell's input should be driven momentarily only, no matter how long the button is depressed. Every time the button is depressed, there should be a positive or negative pulse sent to the input, to flip it.

We can generate such pulses using a differentiator. So, something like the below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f50o7k.png)</sup>

The overall idea is rather simple: C1-R1 forms a low-pass filter that slows down the rise and fall times of the output nQ, so that they don't reach the memory cell input C. Since the differentiator's time constant C2*R2=1ms is much smaller than C1*R1=100ms, the slow changes of the voltage on A are not passed to C.

C1 is discharged via R3, so when the power is lost for more than a second or two, the startup condition will revert to OFF. Short power interruptions will maintain the previous state. This is - presumably - desirable.

When the button is open, both sides of the differentiator capacitor C2 are at the same potential, since it's shorted via R2. C1 is charged to the inverse of the output logic state. When SW1 is depressed, the inverse state on C1 is passed through C2 to the input of the memory cell, flipping its state. After a couple ms, C2 charges up and becomes "open circuit". Further changes of voltage on C1 are slow and cause only small voltage changes on the differentiator output - too small to change the state of the memory cell.

What's left to do is to implement it using transistors. To make the circuit robust, the inverters need to have push-pull or totem-pole outputs with impedance much lower than whatever we connect as a load. Ideally, we'd also want the circuit to consume very little power when idle, to make it useful on battery power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZpyKt.png)</sup>

Each rectangle is a TTL inverter, scaled for 12V operation. The resistor values may need to be adjusted to be more in the center of operating range.

Now we can work on making it consume less power. Using CD40106 as inverters would solve that issue pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

Try a 100 uF capacitor to Q9 pnp transistor between emitter leg (+) and (-) ground (or between positive and negative terminals of 12 volt power input).  When power is first given, surely circuit is off.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the led is connected with a series resistor from the positive supply to Q8 collector there is no reason for that circuit to start up "on"  outside of strong interferance. eg: 50V spikes on the supply could cause spurious turn-ons, if your supply is clean there must be a fault with one of the parts or with how they are connected.

To make it switch slower increase C16

Comment: The LED is connected to Q8 collector via a 2n3906 transistor. The power supply is a clean 12v, no spikes. I tried increasing the capacitor but it only increased the time between being able to switch on or off, not the amount of time it takes to physically push the button.