# NAND-based bistable with momentary switch

Tags: mosfet, switches, inverter, flipflop

I want to create a circuit that has two outputs, and two states, where the outputs are either "on, off" or "off, on".  The state should be switchable using a *momentary* SPST switch.

I am using two inverters from a CD40106.

Here is the current circuit:

[image: cd40106 bistable]

Here, VCC is 9V (the cd40106 is powered by VCC).  The unused inverters have their inputs tied to ground, and the unused outputs are floating.  I used two LEDs to test the "on" and "off" states.

I built this on a breadboard, using red LEDs.  The circuit worked as expected: on power-up, one of the LEDs was lit, the other dark.  Pressing the switch caused the dark LED to light up, and the light LED to go dark.

**Question 1:**
I swapped one of the red LEDs for a *blue* LED.  Now, the blue LED never goes fully dark: it's fully on when the red LED is off, but when the red LED is on, the blue is just a little bit on.

- Using this schematic, assume D2 is the blue LED: even if I jumper Q2's gate to ground, the blue LED is still slightly dim.
- If I completely remove Q2, D2 goes dark.
- I also tried using a diode to connect Q2's gate to ground, with the anode to the gate and cathode to ground: this actually creates a *negative* voltage at Q2's gate (per my DMM).  D2 still never goes completely dark.
- I tried changing the pull-up resistors (R10, R10) to pull-down resistors (i.e. having them go to ground rather than VCC).  D2 still not completely dark.

**Question 2:**
Are the pull-up resistors (R10, R11) actually necessary?  I basically copied this circuit from [this discussion post](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/single-momentary-push-button-for-on-off-(toggling)-a-signal-connection/msg3374316/#msg3374316), where it is suggested to use the pull-up resistors, but doesn't say why.  I've seen countless other variations of this circuit posted in various places on the internet, and don't see them using pull-up (or pull-down) resistors.

Comment: Matt, I think I may have written about something somewhat similar [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/651625/330261).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need Pull-up resistors for those invertors - pull-up resistors are only necessary when you have open-collector outputs. These do not.

If the LED is still on when you short the gate to ground, that means your transistor is destroyed or highly leaky. Try swapping the transistor with either the one that you know works in the circuit or a new one. Also try swapping the position of the Red and Blue LEDs to see if the behavior is the same. If the red LED exhibits the same behavior, it is definitely the transistor. Of course, try swapping the LEDs BEFORE you introduce new transistors into the circuit.

If the blue LED is still behaving the same after being installed in the "known good red LED" side, then it is almost entirely due to leakage - it only takes a few uA to get an LED to glow brightly. The red LED could have the same issue as the blue one, but you just can't perceive it because it has worse luminous efficiency. As a kludge, you can try putting a relatively high (~47k?) resistor across the blue LED to ensure that it stays off even with some leakage. I don't personally like this solution - it's bad design and you shouldn't have to do this. But given the nature of this circuit, it's obviously not that critical. So if it works for your application, it works!

Putting the diode from gate to ground isn't causing any negative voltage; it's not real - you are either measuring wrong or this could be related to the already mentioned leakage issue.

One unlikely reason that you could be having, that I will include for completeness, is that the transistor is acting as an antennae and picking up and rectifying a nearby EMI source. This phenomenon would also explain why you are reading negative voltage on you DMM - it too may be affected by local interference.